# Difference between SDK, SDK platform and SDK Platform Tools

Tags: android, sdk

I was installing android sdk but when I try to use the sdk manager there are lots stuff. Particularly I wonder the difference between SDK, SDK Platform and SDK Platform tools. Any explanations or directions is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> SDK Tools is a downloadable component for the Android SDK. It includes
>   the complete set of development and debugging tools for the Android
>   SDK like emulator, sdcard, sqlite and apk builder etc.. Where as
>   Platform-tools are used to support the features for the current
>   android platform including adb which is acting like a bridge to
>   communicate with emulator or device.